# How to install libquadmath0 in 10.04?

Tags: installation, 10.04, libraries

To compile a package I need to install `libquadmath0` under gcc4.4 10.04 LTS.

I have not found any source. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no `libquadmath0` in the 10.04 repository. It is only available  from 11.10 onwards.

```
$ rmadison libquadmath0
libquadmath0 | 4.6.1-9ubuntu3 |       oneiric | amd64, i386
libquadmath0 | 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 |       precise | amd64, i386
libquadmath0 | 4.7.2-1ubuntu1 |       quantal | amd64, i386
```

You have one of the following choices:

- Upgrade to 11.10 or better
- Grab the deb file from 11.10 or better and install it manually using `dpkg`
- Grab the source and install it